# AbstractUser in Django is not authenticating

Tags: python, django, authentication, passwords

Django version 3.2

I have created a AbstractUser model for storing info of Bank's Customer . I am able to register the customer with username and password . But it's not getting authenticated while login .
In admin page the password is saved as plain text , which is not expected . It should be saved in hashed form by default in Django .
Please give some directions to solve this . What I am doing wrong ?

In settings.py I have added line :
`AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'banking.Customer'`

models.py :

```
'''
    This stores all customers of this bank .
'''
class Customer(AbstractUser):
    #username   = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    #first_name     = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    #last_name  = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    #email      = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    phone       = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    #password   = models.CharField(max_length=2048)
    dateJoined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    # completed, pending, blocked, error
    verificationStatus = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    #USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    #REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.username}, {self.first_name} {self.last_name}, {self.email}, {self.password}"
```

views.py :

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        
        # get the information from form
        print("POST request :" + str(request.POST))
        userName = request.POST["userName"]
        firstName = request.POST["firstName"]
        lastName = request.POST["lastName"]
        email = request.POST["email"]
        phone = request.POST["phone"]
        password = request.POST["password"]

        # insert it in DB, keep in mind that username should be unique
        try:
            customer = Customer(username=userName, first_name=firstName, last_name=lastName, email=email, phone=phone, password=password, verificationStatus="verified")
            customer.save()

            print("Database " + str(customer))
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('login'))
        except:
            # send register page agin with error message
            context = {"message": userName + " userName is already taken ."}
            return render(request, "banking/register.html", context)
    else:
        return render(request, "banking/register.html")



def login(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        # get info from login form
        username = request.POST["userName"]
        password = request.POST["password"]

        # check if user is valid
        customer = None
        try:
            # check if userName exist in DB
            print("check user")
            customer = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        except:
            customer = None
        
        # save customer in session
        if customer is not None:
            login(request, customer)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('mainPage'))
        else:
            # return to login page with error message
            context = {"message": "Invalid credentials"}
            return render(request, "banking/login.html", context) 
    else:
        return render(request, "banking/login.html")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your **register()** method of **views.py**, you have to edit your code to be:

```
customer = Customer(username=userName, first_name=firstName, last_name=lastName, email=email, phone=phone, verificationStatus="verified")
customer.set_password(password)
customer.save()
```

While saving user, we have to set passwords using **set_password()** method, as it will save password using appropriate hash/encryption algorithm.

Comment: I have made the changes as : ```customer = Customer(username=userName, first_name=firstName, last_name=lastName, email=email, phone=phone, verificationStatus="verified")
   customer.set_password(password)
   customer.save() ``` .  But it is not logging in  .

Comment: Can you please elaborate what error or log message are you getting?

Comment: There is no programming error . The expected result is that once the user is registered , then he should be able to login . And yes the password is getting hashed 
```
Saved in database as : peacock, fn ln, e@e.e, pbkdf2_sha256$260000$C3TAdhqgXn93V9reZ2ok10$BOPmOj2b7W8J/TCn2/FZdTyMevFoYibOmiTUxLBJIYk=
```
But somehow I believe this line is not working `customer = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)` in login() function .

Comment: Can you pdb into the method and check what is returned by the authenticate method?

Comment: Amazing it's working now . All this time I have not imported the authenticate() as `from django.contrib.auth import authenticate` . The surprising thing is python is not even giving me any error . It is silently raising the exception and every time it is getting caught by my except code silently .

Comment: Thanks your answer was simple to implement . So I accepted .

Answer (score 0):

You create the customer by using the models `__init__` method (the constructor):

```
customer = Customer(username=userName, first_name=firstName, last_name=lastName, email=email, phone=phone, password=password, verificationStatus="verified")
```

But this does not consider the fact that the password needs to be **hashed** and saves the password as plain text. This causes your user to be unable to login as the `authenticate` function works on the premise that the password is hashed.

You should instead use the [`create_user` [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager.create_user) method of the user model's manager, **UserManager**, which will automatically hash the password:

```
customer = Customer.objects.create_user(username=userName, first_name=firstName, last_name=lastName, email=email, phone=phone, password=password, verificationStatus="verified")
```

Answer (score 0):

When creating the custom `User` class in Django, password encryption and saving mechanism should be handled by the Manager class.
See the code used from the [`EmployeeManager`](https://github.com/astikgabani/Inventory-Management/blob/main/InventoryManagement/employees_api/models.py#L13) class in the [astikgabani/Inventory-Management](https://github.com/astikgabani/Inventory-Management) repository.